# Change only one element after clicking other

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the following problem:

I would like to change the value of an input field, which is next to an another element, which will be clicked.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <a id="{$sArticle.articleID}" class="minus"><i class="icon-minus-wide"></i></a>
   
   <input class="quantityNum--input quantity{$sArticle.articleID}" name="sQuantity" 
   type="text" value="{$sArticle.minpurchase}">

   <a id="{$sArticle.articleID}" class="plus"><i class="icon-plus-wide"></i></a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
     $(document).on('click', ".plus", function (event) {
        let currentTarget = event.currentTarget;

        let idOfClickedElement = $(currentTarget).attr('id');

        let currentQuantity = Number($('.quantity' + idOfClickedElement).val());

        $(this).parent().find(".quantity" + idOfClickedElement).val(currentQuantity + 1)
    });
```

There are other input fields which are the same like in the example. Those value changes also, but I want only one.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to add ` (3 before and 3 after) to the html code ? because currently we only see black area

Comment: sry for that, i forgot it

Comment: `$(this).closest("div").find(".quantityNum--input").val((i, val) => val++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As each input with +/- is inside a div wrapper, you can use

```
$(this).closest("div").find(".quantityNum--input")
```

to get the related input.

There's no need for the numeric IDs when using relative DOM traversal.

Combining the + and - into a single event gives:

```js
$(document).on('click', ".minus,.plus", function() {
  var delta = $(this).is(".plus") ? 1 : -1;
  $(this).closest("div").find(".quantityNum--input").val((i, val) => {
    console.log(val);
    return (val * 1) + delta;
  });
});
```

```css
.minus,
.plus {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="minus">[-]<i class="icon-minus-wide"></i></a>
  <input class="quantityNum--input" name="sQuantity" type="text" value="100">
  <a class="plus">[+]<i class="icon-plus-wide"></i></a>
</div>
<div>
  <a class="minus">[-]<i class="icon-minus-wide"></i></a>
  <input class="quantityNum--input" name="sQuantity" type="text" value="500">
  <a class="plus">[+]<i class="icon-plus-wide"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: after reloading the page, the behaviour disappears

Answer (score 0):

I thik you are looking for [`.next`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.prev`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/).

note: I like sharing information usingdata-attributes so I've used that. you can use anything else `id/class` to differentiate. that's upto you

Just created a demo script for you

```js
$('.number-action-button').on('click', function(){
  const direction = $(this).data('direction');
  if(direction === 'decrement'){
    const $input = $(this).next('input[type="number"]');
    $input.val($input.val() - 1);
  }

  if(direction === 'increment'){
    const $input = $(this).prev('input[type="number"]');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 1);
  }
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="number-action-button"  data-direction="decrement">-</button>
<input type="number" value="0" />
<button class="number-action-button" data-direction="increment" >+</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but keep in mind there are more input fields which are looking 100% the same but placed in another DOM.

Comment: if they are following the same hierarchy `+ button -> input -> button` , it should take care of it

Comment: Yea it is the same hierarchy

Comment: Just a note: be careful with `.next(selector)` as it's the same as `.next().filter(selector)` , it's *not* `.nextAll().filter(selector).first()` which it looks like it should be.

Answer (score -1):

simple solution: bundle the 3 elemts into 1 container, so your parent selector can easily catch the input, the way you already do it.

```
<div>
  <a id="{$sArticle.articleID}" class="minus"><i class="icon-minus-wide"></i></a>
   
   <input class="quantityNum--input quantity{$sArticle.articleID}" name="sQuantity" 
   type="text" value="{$sArticle.minpurchase}">

   <a id="{$sArticle.articleID}" class="plus"><i class="icon-plus-wide"></i></a>
</div>
```

if you cant(or dont want) change the html use  `$(this).next()` (or `$(this).prev()` for the plus button) in order to fint the input.

btw: maybe you'll try that funktion (havn't tested it, but at least it should give you an idea how to)

```
$(document).on('click', ".plus,.minus", function (event) {
    let input_quantity=false;
    if($(this).hasClass('plus'){
        input_quantity=$(this).prev();
        input_quantity.val(parseInt(input_quantity.val())+1);
    }else{
        input_quantity=$(this).next();
        input_quantity.val(parseInt(input_quantity.val())-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i have already bundled them into one div

Comment: another posibility, if you got the posibility to manipulate the html is that you add an data-input_class="quantity{$sArticle.articleID}" to the +-buttons. and then use $('.'+$(this).data('input_class')).val() in order to get/set the inputs val. the you dont have to take care, where the input is located in your DOM (beside: instead of the class, an ID attribute would be nicer on the input)